# View is not being updated when calling UIButton.isHidden = true/false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am using `xcode 8.2` and `swift` to make a simple application.

I have added a `UIButton` to my View using the `Interface Builder`.

I have added the appropriate outlets for the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!
```

I want this button to be hidden on start so in `viewDidLoad` I am setting is to `Hidden`. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        ...
        myBtn.isHidden = true
        ...
        mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iphone7", host: "192.xx.xx.150", port: 18xx, keepAlive: 60)

        mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
            if ( mqttMessage.topic == "status" ) {
                if ( mqttMessage.payloadString?.localizedStandardContains("show") )! {
                    self.showButton = true
                } else if ( mqttMessage.payloadString?.localizedStandardContains("hide")  )! {
                    self.showButton = false
                }
                self.showHideSeatButtons()
            } else {
                // something to do in case of other topics
            }
        }
```

Later in the code I have a function to show/hide this button.

```
func showHideButton(){
    if ( self.showButton ) {
        print("button enabled!")
        myBtn.isHidden = false

    } else {
        print("button disabled!")
        myBtn.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

When I call this function (by receiving a certain message using MQTT) I get the print outs but I don't see the button.
If I press where I know the button is, then the button gets shown.

Any idea what could be going on here? I have spent and hour googling this now! Please don't suggest `object-c` way of solving this issue, as I don't know `object-c`.

Comment: `self.showButton` value isn't changed afterwards? What about `myBtn.isHidden = !myBtn.isHidden` instead?

Comment: at the same time as using .isHIdden, have you tried to disable interaction and enable them again when you're button gets shown again. myBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false. 
Plus, where do you set the boolean showButton and where do you call showHideButton from?

Comment: myBtn action is  showHideButton,

Comment: I don't  know where do you call your showHideButton method. Try calling it in the main thread : DispatchQueue.main.async {
}

Comment: Are you working on another thread?

Comment: I added mor info above

Comment: set myBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue  -to see if button is actually turning visible or not.

Comment: What is UI Of your button in XIB? You have added some image to it?

Comment: MQTT probably works in another thread, try setting your button on the main thread.

Comment: @Hapeki how can I do that?

Comment: where is showButton set to true?

Comment: please see updated question, I have added more code.

Comment: @theAlse solved your problem....? or still facing any issue...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In onMessageCallback block

Replace following line

```
self.showHideSeatButtons()
```

with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.showHideSeatButtons()
}
```

**Note**: UI related changes/updates must be handled by main queue (thread).

Answer (score 4):

Since you're calling a service it's possible you're not working in the same thread. Try this:

```
func showHideButton(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (self.showButton ) {
                print("button enabled!")
                self.myBtn.isHidden = false

            } else {
                print("button disabled!")
                self.myBtn.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
myBtn.isHidden = true
myBtn.alpha = 0
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.